# Create file in OneDrive

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow, word

[image]

I have a flow which creates a Word document file in OneDrive. When the flow runs the Word documents get created but never opens. Attached are the pictures of flow and when I tried to open the document.

[image]

Comment: Where is the File Content coming from? Do you get the same error in Desktop version of Word?

Comment: @Michael Colbs the file content is comming from one drive. when i try to open on desktop it wont still open.

Comment: If you replace that object in File Content with a hard-coded string, does it open?

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. The get items i was using had issue with the value set as ID.The Column was Master ID on my list but flow interpreted as Master_x002ID

Answer (score 0):

Commonly when you get this error, it means the file content you are using are not proper. The file content field needs to be filled with binary object. And I am not sure the dynamic content you are using meets the requirements.

In my end, using the action `get file content` from OneDrive actions will provide the correct content for create file, please have a try.
[image]